# You are going the wrong way / on the wrong way

Tags: sentence-construction

1. You are going **the wrong way.**
2. You are going **on the wrong way.**

As a learner I commonly use the second one to remind someone who has taken the wrong road to get to his destination.

But today I came across the first one, which has been used to express the same meaning.

Is **"the wrong way"** an adverb here?

Which is more correct to use? Explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

"The way" is *not* the same as "the road".

"Way" in this context refers to a *direction*. One cannot be described as being "on" a direction, but you can be on a road which has a physical surface.

The correct versions of your examples would therefore be:

> You are going the wrong way.
>
> You are on the wrong road.

Remember you could be on the *right* road, but going the *wrong way*! So do not expect the two to be interchangeable.